# Potenciación con python

Tags: python, math

Salida Esperada

```
y = -1.0
y = 3.0
y = -9.0
```

> Ya he realizado lo siguiente sin embargo, no concuerda con los datos que me muestra en la salida esperada

```
x = float(0)
print("Y=",(x**3)-(x**2)+(3*x)-1)
x = float(1)
print("Y=",(x**3)-(x**2)+(3*x)-1)
x = float(-1)
print("Y=",(x**3)-(x**2)+(3*x)-1)
```

luego de que la publicación obtuvo una calificación negativa

Pude deducir que lo siguiente me sirve para una respuesta:

```
x = float(0)
print("Y=",(3*x**3))
x = float(1)
print("Y=",(3*x**3)-(2*x**2)+(3*x**3)-1)
x = float(-1)
print("Y=",(3*x**3)-(2*x**2)+(3*x**3)-1)
```

Comment: Hola! No hay una pregunta en tu enunciado. ¿Cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: Operaciones con potencia amigo, el enunciado explica que se debe econtrar el valor de y, para evaluar los resultados esta la formula de dicho enunciado repito. 
3x3 - 2x2 + 3x - 1 
se debe evaluar x = 0 Ejemplo. 3(0**3 - 2) -2x2 + 3x-1

Comment: Y qué problema tienes con eso. ¿Algo relacionado con programación?

Comment: @Alfabravo si de hecho el resultado es este 

y = -1.0

y = 3.0

y = -9.0

lo unico que debo expresar ese resultado dependiendo de la formula

Comment: @BetaM Editado, siempre estas pendiente incluso de las prreguntas y sabe que anteriormente hemos discutido, deberias esperar que la pregunta o el bloque de lo que hagamos este listo, por favor corrije y valora. no es la primera pregunta que participas en la que escribo

Comment: deberia haber un tiempo en el que apunta el negativo, espere hasta que se termine de revisar y pasar por un moderador

Comment: Es nuestra responsabilidad individual formular preguntas de acuerdo a los lineamientos, que están ahí para obtener respuesta más fácil. Ej: tu fórmula es `3(x^3) - 2(x^2) + 3x - 1`??? No es evidente

Comment: @BetaM coloco la editada, enunciado como me lo presenta la academy

Comment: @Alfabravo por favor verifica, que la pregunta haya sido modificada. que estes seguro que existe una pregunta.

Comment: @Alfabravo Es justo que este en -3 por un error o redacción desde la academy ? es decir interpretación de la redacción de una institución. al final coloque el post como muestra el enunciado que ellos publican. el otro se salio del contexto no le importó "@BetaM"

Comment: @Alfabravo yo entiendo perfectamente, que es su responsabilidad, entonces me estoy haciendo responsable de mejorar lo mas que pueda para que el  usuario que lea  entienda lo que lee. me parece que puede ser así 3(x^3) - 2(x^2) + 3x - 1 tomando en cuenta que para cada uno deberia haber un resultado, y el resultado lo estoy mostrado lo que necesitaba era el procedimiento y para eso estoy acudiendo a la publicación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según como entiendo lo que deseas hacer es, a la variable `x` potenciarla al valor que se encuentra a su derecha, ejemplo, para 2X2 es "`2x²`".

Lo que puedes hacer en este caso para representar la formula en Python es usar el operador `**` que se usa para la potencia.

### Variables

```
x1 = 0
x2 = 1
x3 = -1
```

### Formula

```
y = 3*(x1**3) - 2*(x2**2) - 3*(x3) -1
```

Con esto lo que representas es `y = 3x³ - 2x² - 3x -1`

Comment: Tu respuesta es correcta. sin embargo el formato es de la primera version jajaja aunque si funciona! todo es cuestión de dar el formato correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar > 3x3 - 2x2 + 3x - 1 hacemos:

```
x1 = 0
x2 = 1
x3 = -1

x1 = float(x1)
y = 3*(x1**3) - 2*(x1**2) + 3*(x1) -1
print("y =", y)

x2 = 1
x2 = float(x2)
y = 3*(x2**3) - 2*(x2**2) + 3*(x2) -1
print("y =", y)

x3 = -1
x3 = float(x3)
y = 3*(x3**3) - 2*(x3**2) + 3*(x3) -1
print("y =", y)
```